# operator expected in prolog while reading a file

Tags: prolog

I am getting an error when i tried to read a file as operator expected.

```
   main:- 
         open('cr1.txt',read,Str), 
         read_houses(Str,Houses), 
         close(Str), 
         write(Houses),  nl. 

   read_houses(Stream,[]):- 
         at_end_of_stream(Stream). 

   read_houses(Stream,[X|L]):- 
         \+  at_end_of_stream(Stream), 
         read(Stream,X), 
         read_houses(Stream,L).
```

Comment: Paste the error you get in order to better get help! (edit the question and add it there)

Comment: What does the content of `cr1.txt` look like? The `read/2` predicate reads *valid prolog terms* from the input file. If they don't match that description, you can get an error.